# Javascript в href

Tags: html, javascript

Есть открывок html кода:

```
<a href="javascript:" target="_blank" ></a>
```

Мне нужно сделать чтобы при клике на эту ссылку вызывалась моя функция. Но эксплорер из-за `target="_blank"` открывает новое окно, как от этого избавиться?
**Мне нужно менять содержимое только href.**

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоаться, почему менять можно только `href`? Какая религия не позволяет вам написать нормальный обработчик клика?

Comment: В клиенте к сайту создаётся объект, в котором нужно указывать ссылку. Для одного из объектов, при клике на него, должно открываться окно.

Comment: Если return false; не помогает, то можно попробовать вставить onclick "незаконно", указав такой href (сработает, только если CMS не экранирует кавычки): #" onclick="myfunc();return false;" qq="

Comment: Javascript:void(0);return false;

Comment: Алексей, спасибо, хоть и коряво, но помогло. Олег, вопрос полностью прочитай